# How to ignore $-prefixed properties when iterating with angular.forEach?

Tags: angularjs

[Example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3rJwXVaCjd6QZYEMnoQ?p=preview)

I have an object that contains other objects, like so:

```
var collection = {
  $type: 'people',
  '2a4a24': {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
  '457b9c': {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
  '59d8ae': {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
};
```

If I use `ng-repeat`, then the `$type` property is ignored. However, when I use `angular.forEach`, the `$type` property is included in the iteration.

This seems inconsistent to me. How do I iterate over the collection object while ignoring $-prefixed properties? Do I have to manually check `key.charAt(0) !== '$'`?

Comment: I think you may have to... I personally haven't seen anything that would suggest otherwise

Comment: In most cases it's possible to prevent angular from adding `$` properties to your objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to do that yourself. Angular does that automaticly in some directives to prevent it from iterating over it's internal properties which always start with a dollarsign. There's a issue raised on the tracker about this:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6266

But your absolutely right, it comes over as inconsistent because it is totally undocumented in the API's of the affected directives.

Your `key.charAt(0) !== '$'` will do the trick:

```
angular.forEach($scope.people, function (person, key) {
  if (key.charAt(0) !== '$') {
    $scope.myData.push(person);
  }
});
```